Transformation Function Possibilities
Given an unknown input I that is transformed by a known function T and produces and output O from a set of transformation functions F. Can we devise a set of transformations functions F that allows us to find the transformation function T through elimination or "something" that was used to produce the output O
Where I can be any length And O can also be any length.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This is much too vague.  If you [edit] the question to tell us what kind of functions $T$ and $F$ are and what "devise" means and the range of inputs we may be able to help. As asked, the answer to your question is just "no".
